# render wpf control on screen one by one with some delay

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying a little animation in my wpf application.
There is a WPF Form that contain 5 rectangular shape `Border` and i want then to load with little delay.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<StackPanel>
<Border name="Border1"/>
<Border name="Border2"/>
<Border name="Border3"/>
<Border name="Border4"/>
<Border name="Border5"/>
</stackpanel>
```

I just want to render them on screen one by one with some delay.

Comment: Can't you just use animations that have different Durations

Comment: I have no experience and prior knowledge in animation in wpf. So if it is a way then please post the link or atleast the terms so that i can google them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a storyboard. Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364529/Animation-using-Storyboards-in-WPF) for some great examples.